# Hiding parent div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm enlarging images on click and moving them so they don't go off the page. I have a parent div behind each that is black pic so that when I hover, I can change the opacity of the pic to make it look like it's darkening. All of this works fine, however, when I enlarge and move the photo there is a black box left behind. I need that to disappear but when I try it makes the child pic disappear too.

here's the code, jsfiddle posted beneath

HTML

```
<div id="Gpic1">
    <img class='galleryPics' id='pic1' src='http://i.imgur.com/urxD24P.jpg?1'>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#Gpic1 {
float: left;
width: 187px;
height: 280px;
margin-left: 5%;
display: inline-block;
background: black;
padding: 0;
}

#pic1{
width: 187px;
height: 280px;
}

.enlarged {
    border: 10px solid #e5dbcc;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.75);`
}
```

JQUERY

```
 $('#Gpic1').hover(function () {
 if (!$(this).find('img').hasClass('enlarged')) {
     $(this).find('img').fadeTo(500, 0.5);
 }


}, function () {
     $(this).find('img').fadeTo(500, 1);
 });

 $('#pic1').click(function () {
     $(this).fadeTo(0, 1);
 if ($(this).hasClass('enlarged')) {
     $(this).removeClass('enlarged');

     $(this).stop().animate({
         width: 187,
         height: 280
     }, 0,

     function () {
         $(this).parent().removeClass('ontop');
     });
 } else {
     $(this).addClass('enlarged')
     $(this).parent().addClass('ontop');
     $(this).stop().animate({
         width: 533,
         height: 800,
         left: +590,
         bottom: +50
     }, 200);

 }

 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this at the end of the animate for the  pic onClick Event

```
$('#Gpic1').css('background','none');
```

Here is a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Td6tT/3/

Comment: This worked for when the picture was enlarged, but left the black background out on the second onClick event that returns the pic to it's original size, causing it to look wrong when hovered over. I added your code and a line to fix that issue. Here is the fiddle with the final working code: http://jsfiddle.net/Td6tT/3/

Answer (score 0):

When you try to remove `#Gpic1`, all children are removed even if they are absolutely positioned.

If you just want the black background to go away, you can remove the black background from the containing div.

```
$("#Gpic1").css("background-color", "transparent");
```

Or, if you really want to remove the containing div, then you will need to make the image a child of some other object on the page.  If you're using absolute positioning, then you could just make the image a child of the body object instead of #Gpic1 so then you can remove #Gpic1 and the image won't disappear.

```
// move pic1 to be a child of the body so we can remove Gpic1
$("#pic1").appendTo(document.body);
$("#Gpic1").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('#Gpic1').css('background','none');`